Is "metro" used in British English?
This is an IELTS essay question I saw on a website. IELTS is a British test. Is the use of metros strange? Don't the British use 'underground railways'?

Some cities have vehicle-free days when private cars, trucks and
motorbikes are banned from city centres. People are encouraged to use
public transport such as buses, taxis and metros on vehicle free days.
Do the advantages of having vehicle-free days outweigh the
disadvantages?


No, metros is perfectly understood here. The system in Newcastle and area is called the Tyne and Wear Metro, for example.

@DanielRoseman - yes, and the Bristol area has MetroWest, formerly the Greater Bristol Metro. Proposed systems include Cambridge Metro, Glasgow Metro, and Taunton metro rail. The term is widely understood, both among transport professionals and the wider public, to signify an reasonably high-frequency service, close station spacing, etc. Bristol also has a 'MetroBus' bus rapid transit system', in addition to the normal buses.

The original one, in London, is called the (London) Underground, but the Paris Metro(politain) is also so well-known that some other British systems have borrowed the term.

@KateBunting - faute d'orthographe.... Métro...

But in fact the Paris one is named after the original Metropolitan Railway, in London (now the Metropolitan Line of the tube).

@DanielRoseman - Interesting - I didn't know that.

Le Monde called a new London Overground line, a lot of which is on viaducts, a métro aérien. They do use that term for elevated parts of the Paris system.

I don't find it perfectly idiomatic when used in the plural, whereas "the metro" (lowercase) would seem natural to me even though locally we call it the subway.  I think metros is a relatively new development.

@KateBunting - I'm a bit sceptical; the Metropolitan Railway was a metropolitan railway, after all, and so was the one operated by the Compagnie du chemin de fer métropolitain de Paris.

The underground/subway/metro is a system; the cars themselves are not called "metros" (not that I know of at least) and that is the effect of including the word in the plural form in a list:  "buses, taxis, and metros".

@TimR - would you not think it reasonable to say that there are metros in Moscow, Buenos Aires, Beijing, and Copenhagen, among other cities?

@MichaelHarvey Yes, but I'd understand that to mean "systems of underground trains".  I wouldnt use "metros" in a list of vehicle types:  buses, taxis, trolleys, and metros

@TimR - I do find it annoying when Londoners say or write 'I was in a tube that stopped in the tunnel for 20 minutes'. To me (born there) 'the Tube' is the system. What runs on it are Tube (or Underground) trains.

Taxis aren't public transport!

@JamesK True. Some cities, though, have rules requiring taxis to have hybrid engines, so that in stop-and-go traffic they're using the electric motor. The original could be "fixed" to say "public or municipally approved".

Definitions of public transport vary, and taxis may or may not count. Airplanes are often not included, despite the fact that you buy tickets and sit next to strangers. OTOH, cycle hire schemes are often included (especially if organised by the city council), as possibly are car clubs or car sharing, and taxi-bus, shared taxi, or similar would qualify; tourist things like cable cars, funiculars, etc, too. It depends who's doing the organization or providing the information. A city may list everything it runs under "public transport", while an environmental group may list everything "green".

BETTER:  On vehicle free days, people are encouraged to use public transport such as buses, taxis and metros. There we go now. It's not the use of metro that is strange, it is the placement of the prepositional phrase that is.

@JamesK - Taxis in London are licensed by Transport for London (TfL), who also regulate fares and specify who drivers must carry - unless they have a good reason not to, drivers must accept any hiring up to 12 miles (20 miles if starting at Heathrow Airport) or up to one hour duration, if the destination is in Greater London. The famous TfL roundel has a version for taxi matters. I'd say that was public transport.

I'd say the exact opposite!  If I'm in a taxi and the taxi driver stops and takes another fare at the same time as me I'd be a little upset.  Once it is hired it is private and the taxi driver can't take additional passengers.  In the context of the quote, "public transport" is contrasted with "cars". Taxis are more like privately hired cars than buses or trains.


Is "metro" used in British English?

When talking about particular transport systems in particular cities, different cities use different terms. For example.

In Glasgow you have the "Subway".
In Tyne and Wear (Newcastle/Sunderland) you have the "Metro".
In Greater London you have the "Underground" and the "Docklands light railway".

When talking generally "Metro" usually refers to a high-frequency system that runs on rails along their own dedicated right of way. This is distinct from "Trams" which share all or part of their rights of way with road vehicles and/or pedestrians.
Lines can get blurry though, the Manchester Metrolink has "Metro" in it's name despite not meeting the generally agreed definition of "Metro". Legally it's a tram, but the tram status was very much downplayed in the early years of the network to distance the new network from run-down tramways that had been withdrawn a few decades earlier.

Don't the British use 'underground railways'?

Metro is not Synonomous with Underground railway. While many large metro systems do have their core sections underground, because that was deemed the most practical way to run the lines through existing cities, this isn't always the case.
The docklands light railway (DLR) is clearly a metro, but it's not an underground railway. When the system was first built it had no underground sections, a few short underground sections were added later to cross the river and provide a better connection to central London but the system is still overwhelmingly above ground.
Equally the Thameslink and Cross-rail cores in London and the underground sections of Merseyrail in Liverpool are definitely underground railways (though not part of the London Underground) but they don't meet the general definition of Metro since they are part of the National rail network.

While "a metro" would be understood as a light, underground rail system for a city, it sounds odd to talk about the trains as "metros".
However this exposes a linguistic gap in English, there isn't a word to mean "a light train designed for cities and often running underground". If I'd written this I'd have used "trains", "the metro" or just omitted it to avoid the problem.
Also, taxis aren't public transport, they are privately hired!

'Metro', short for metropolitan, is a broad term that is used to refer to many city railway systems, both underground and overground. The original London city railway was called "The Metropolitan Railway".
The official name for London's rapid transit system is "The London Underground", so that is a specific name for the current London metro. It's nickname is "The Tube".
So you could use the term 'metro' in connection with London so long as you're being broad. I wouldn't call it 'the' metro, because that would suggest it is its proper name. Also bear in mind that one of the lines on the current network is called 'The Metropolitan Line' so it could cause confusion if you're not clear.
